# How to change the look of exchange mail login page?

Tags: css, html, edit, exchange-server

I need to change the exchange mail default look. Like,
[image: default exchange mail look]

to

[image]

I just need to find the design folders where I can make the changes. I need to change the CSS too. Not only the image change will be much help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SharePoint.

However, you might want to take a look at [this article](http://www.careexchange.in/how-to-customize-the-outlook-web-app-owasign-in-page-in-exchange-2013/), [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHjmMpR6Oto) and, of course, [the official documentation at Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633483%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). Or try asking at Server Fault

Comment: Thanks a lot. specially I needed the directory "V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth\version\themes\resources"